# Firebase not sending any emails

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have configured email verification and password email reset in my firebase project, it used to work fine, I tested it multiple times, but suddenly it stopped working and I am not recieving any email.
I tried checking spam but still, there was nothing.

Here's my code for sending email verification after registering user:

```
user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please verifiy your email and sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerificationActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I also tried to make a button that re-send the email but I get the following message "we have stopped all traffic from this device due to unsual activity"

```
verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, "Verification email has been sent, check spam if you are unable to find it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

my code for email reset:

```
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() { //email is entered by the user
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void unused) { 
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Reset email sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
});
```

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry to tag you but i'm really stuck here, do you know what is causing this issue?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My best solution was to switch my android app to a new firebase project.